# Bayes' Theorem and Total Probability Theorem problem.

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

> A bag contains *n* balls out of which some balls are white. The probability that the bag contains *i* white balls is proportional to $i^2$. A ball is drawn at random from the bag and found to be white. Then find the probability that the bag contains exactly 2 white balls.

I found the probability of drawing the ball that's proportional to *i* but not any more.

My attempt:

Let the event of drawing the ball be $A_i$.

Its given that $P(A_i)$ is proportional to $i^2$,
then $P(A_i)= k~i^2$.

Taking total probability, $1=k\sum_{i=0}^n i^2$

$k= 1/(\sum_{i=0}^n(i^2))$

Therefore, $P(A_i)= \dfrac{(6~i^2)}{n(n+1)(2 n+1)}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the constant $i$"?  the condition is that $P(X=i)=\lambda i^2$ for each $i$ (where $X$ denotes the number of white balls).  Did you compute $\lambda$?  If so...edit your post to include that result.

Comment: No, what is given that the probability that the bag contains $i$ white ball is proportional to $i^2$.  Your calculations are correct, but your interpretation is askew. Your $A_i$ is the event that the bag contains $i$ white balls.

Comment: The probability that the bag contains $i$ white balls *and* one of these is drawn is thus $\mathsf P(D\cap A_i)={\big(6~i^3\big)}/{\big(n^2~(n+1)~(2n+1)\big)}$, which leads to the answers given below.  (Basically, the calculation of the constant of proportionality was an unnecessary diversion).

Answer (score 3):

We want to compute:

$$\begin{align}
P(i=2 \,| \,\text{white ball is drawn}) &= \dfrac{P(\text{white ball is drawn}\, | \,i=2) \cdot P(i=2)}{P(\text{white ball is drawn})} \\
&=\dfrac{\dfrac{2}{n} \cdot (\lambda\cdot 2^2)}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\lambda \cdot i^2 \cdot \dfrac{i}{n}} \\
&=\dfrac{\dfrac{8}{n}}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\dfrac{i^3}{n}} \\
&=\dfrac{8}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}i^3} \\
&=\dfrac{8}{(n(n+1)/2)^2} \\
&=\dfrac{32}{(n(n+1))^2} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: $\frac{i}{n} = \lambda \cdot i^2$ is not true. The probability of drawing a white ball is not necessarily equal to the probability that there are $i$ white balls.

Comment: @jfarchione It's not being assumed anywhere in the solution -- that bit was from an earlier version of the post I had forgotten to remove before I understood what the problem was asking.

Comment: I thought it was odd that you had included that bit although it appeared nowhere in your solution. But, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

We are looking for the probability that the number of white balls is 2 given that we have already selected a white ball. So, we are looking for 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{Pr}(X = 2 \cap B = w)}{\text{Pr}(B=w)}
\end{equation}
Where $X$ is the number of white balls and $B$ is the ball drawn. It is given to us that $\text{Pr}(X = i) = \lambda \cdot i^2$. We can see that 
\begin{equation*}
\text{Pr}(X = 2 \cap B = w) = (\lambda \cdot  2^2) \cdot \frac{2}{n} = \frac{8\lambda}{n}
\end{equation*}

Now, to find $\text{Pr}(B=w)$, we need the sum 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda\cdot i^2) \cdot \frac{i}{n}
\end{equation*}
This is the sum of the probabilities that the number of white balls is $i$ and we choose a white ball. Finally, we substitute these into the expression above so that we have 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\frac{8\lambda}{n}}{\sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda\cdot i^2) \cdot \frac{i}{n}} = 
\frac{8}{\sum_{i=1}^n i^3} = \frac{8}{\frac{1}{4}(n(n+1))^2} = \frac{32}{(n(n+1))^2}
\end{equation}
This is the probability that number of white balls is 2 given that we have chosen a white ball.